# Query dynamoDB with non hash key field (with boto / python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using dynamoDB with boto, and having a bit of a problem in the design/query of my table.

I'd like my data to look something like

```
+---------------------------------------+
hash_key    account_id    mykey
-----------------------------------------
1           12345         myvalue1
2           12345         myvalue2
3           12345         myvalue3
4           123456        myvalue4
+---------------------------------------+
```

And then retrieve all data for account 12345. Looking at the boto docs, I always need to have the hash_key available. I know how I would query this standard SQL / MongoDB, but I can't find a solution for boto. I assume this is possible? Thanks!

**EDIT: This seems to work**

```
+---------------------------------------+
hash_key    range_key    mykey
-----------------------------------------
12345       12568        myvalue1
12345       53890        myvalue2
12345       12322        myvalue3
123456      23432        myvalue4
+---------------------------------------+
```

Followed by

```
> res = table.query(hash_key='12345')
> for item in res:
>    print i
```

Since I want to grab all the entries with account # 12345, regardless of the range_key, I need to **query** instead of **get_item**

Comment: Did you ever experience a 'UnknownFilterTypeError' when querying like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the account_id as the `hash_key` along with some `range_key` to differentiate them.

In DynamoDB, the primary key is composed of a (`hash_key`, `range_key`) `range_key` being optional. This tuple needs to be unique. Note that you will need the whole tuple to access a given element with `get_item`.

Having an 'auto_increment' `hash_key` is a bad habit from the SQL world.

If you want to know more on this subject, I wrote some background do on modeling data in the dynamodb-mapper documentation: http://dynamodb-mapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model.html#auto-increment-when-to-use

Comment: that's what I wanted originally, but the hash_key needs to be unique!

Comment: Yeah, use ``range_key`` to differentiate them. If you have more background on the model, I can try to suggest one.

Comment: I see - just tested, and indeed dynamoDB allows the same hash_key if you add the range_key. I guess the value I give to range_key is irrelevant (as long as it's unique), since I only use it to differentiate the entries? The data are actually GPS points that are inserted periodically. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to reflect your comment. Note that you will need the whole (``hash_key``, ``range_key``) tuple to access a random element. Btw, If this solves your issue, you may consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: Also added an edit - looks like `query` is what I was after - not sure of the performance implications here though.

Comment: Query is quite efficient and will not cost more than "GET" for a single item.