# How to send chunks of data to AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-sqs

Based on the [node documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property) for `sqs.sendMessage` "*you now have the ability to send large payload messages that are up to 256KB (262,144 bytes) in size*", so my messages happen to be bigger than this size! What is the best solution in this case? Is there anyway to send chunks of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution that will allow you to exceed the 256k max message size for a sqs message, but you could store the object, whatever it is, in s3 for example (or a database) and just use SQS for the queuing part of your solution with a pointer of some sort as part of the message in SQS and then as part of the Q processing retrieve the extra data from s3 or the database as needed.

Comment: Using S3 as backing storage for large data (while keeping a pointer to the data in the main dataset) is a common pattern - I made a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370814/is-this-an-appropriate-use-case-for-amazon-dynamodb-nosql/26372225#26372225).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look at the workaround implemented in [sns-sqs-big-payload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sns-sqs-big-payload)

In two words the idea of this package is when it exceeds limits to store message contents in S3.